# How can I create a method that returns an array of IDs?

Tags: php, symfony, methods, doctrine

I try to create a method that returns an array of IDs:

```
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", mappedBy="project")
    *
    * @Serializer\Expose()
    */
    private $event;



    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->enabled = false;
        $this->event = new ArrayCollection();
    }


     /**
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     *
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("event")
     */
    public function getEvent(): ?array
    {
        if ($event = $this->getEvent()) {
            return [
                'id' => $event->getId(),
            ];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I get an error message in my console:

> The "selection" field with the path "event/" expects an array of ids
> as value but received an array of objects instead. Is it possible that
> your API returns an array serialized objects?

To fix this I tried:

```
  public function getEvent()
    {
        return $this->event;
    }


        /**
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     *
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty()
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("event")
     */
    public function getEventData(): ?array
    {
        if ($event = $this->getEvent()) {
            return [
                'id' => $event->getId(),
            ];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But here I get the error message:

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "getId" of class
> "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$event is a OneToMany relationship, which mean it would be better if you renamed it `$events`.

`$event` is an ArrayCollection made of `Event` object.

Which mean that if you want to get an array made only of ids, you need to turn your ArrayCollection into an array of ID.

So you could use ArrayCollection `map` method to apply a callback on each element to return an array of id.

Example:

```
public function getEventData(): ?array
    {
        return $this->event->map(fn($e) => $e->getId())->toArray();
    }
```

[map (from doctrine doc)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/1.6/index.html#map)

> Applies the given function to each element in the collection and
> returns a new collection with the elements returned by the function.

We use toArray to turn the ArrayCollection into an array.